# Does MD5 hash have quasi commutative property?

Tags: md5

I am implementing a one-way accumulator using MD5 hash, wondering wheather it has quasi commutative property or not.

Comment: What do *you* mean by quasi-commutative?  Please expand your question with additional details, examples, etc. to clarify what you are asking.  Also, tell us what you've tried and what research you've done.

Comment: @D.W. Guess we could call this a quasi-question. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not. There are only a few cryptographically strong functions that have that quality out there. lattice based methods are promising.