# Does SHA-1 hash have quasi commutative property?

Tags: sha-1

Although I have tested with a program and found negative answer, I want to be sure.

Comment: Are you going to ask the same question for SHA-2 and SHA-3 as well? http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20497/does-md5-hash-have-quasi-commutative-property

Comment: Sorry for that.. actually I am implementing a scheme that requires a hash with this property, I tried both md5 and SHA-1 but not sure I am doing it right.

Comment: No, no standard hash will have that quality as it has to be very specifically designed as a quasi-commutative hash, even then, they tend to look more like public key systems than a hash. Using a bignum library capable of implementing RSA, you should be able to implement the modular exponentiation version mentioned in the original paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $\operatorname{SHA-1}$ does not have any property remotely similar to the [quasi-commutative property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-commutative_property#Applied_to_functions), that
$$\forall x,\forall  y_1,\forall y_2, f(f(x,y_1),y_2)=f(f(x,y_2),y_1)$$

That's for that natural mapping of $f(x,y)$ to $f(x\|y)$, where $\|$ stands for concatenation. No function (except trivially narrow) can exhibit such property and also aim at being similar to a random function. And the only striking property distinguishing $\operatorname{SHA-1}$ from a random function (beside being $\operatorname{SHA-1}$) is that it has the length-extension property (which allows, given $\operatorname{SHA-1}(x)$ and the length of $x$, to exhibit non-empty $y$ such that $\operatorname{SHA-1}(x||y)$ is known).